# Flutter web - Performance problems (hot-reload)

Tags: flutter, performance, canvas, flutter-web, webassembly

I'm having performance issues after changing any code. The hot-reload reloads the full page and then starts my API calls again as a consequence. These increases spend time to make a simple layout change.

I already searched about the **hot-reload/hot-restart** but don't find a satisfactory result and I know that flutter uses a canvas to paint a "*fake*" webpage. So this makes me think it has some way to reload a change without repainting a full page again. To small apps, this doesn't seem a problem but if you work thinking in scalability it's.

**About our development environment:**

- Docker (*image [emirdeliz/flutter](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/emirdeliz/flutter)*)
- Multi-repo approach (*we have a lot of small projects as dependencies*).
- Vscode (*using the launch.json like below*)

```json
{
    "name": "Web hom",
    "cwd": "flut_base_web",
    "program": "lib/main_hom.dart",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "args": ["--web-port", "8080", "--web-renderer", "auto", "--hot"]
}
```

**And below is the performance report from chrome after a change:**

[image]

Anyway, is there any way to decrease the time to reload the page after some changes?

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is no hot-reload on flutter web

Comment: You're right. But I would like to know if has a workaround to improve the reload time.